# Better Google PageSpeed results for Serverless Angular 6 App (AWS Static Hosting)

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, angular6, serverless, google-pagespeed

Currently, my personal website hosted on AWS S3 bucket (static hosting) gets very very poor results on Google PageSpeed: 32/100 (In my Rails app I have currently 92/100 so I am not to sure why its so low for Angular)

I choose Angular because I thought it would do best practices for Google's Browser. It seems either I was wrong or I did something horribly wrong with my application (which is most likely the reason).

I ran `ng build --prod --aot` and hosted this within an AWS S3 bucket

- Are there any frameworks/plugins that can help me to meet the recommended below?
- Should I use server-side rendering instead? (I tried lazy loading, but didn't see better results)
- Does anyone have an example app with best practices for page speed?

[image: Google PageSpeed Results: www.abebraham.com]

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.abebraham.com

Comment: This is an overkill "ng build --prod --aot" because "ng build --prod" already does AOT so the last parameter is not needed. Source: https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Comment: Oh, silly me. Nice catch there! 

Totally explains why I saw no difference in performance when I used `--aot`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would help:

1 Run event handlers

2 Update data bindings

3 Propagate DOM updates and repaint

https://blog.angular.io/3-tips-for-angular-runtime-performance-from-the-real-world-d467fbc8f66e